# Bash replace prefix with spaces

Tags: string, bash, prefix

How to remove prefix from string in Bash?

For example:

```
STRING1="My name is James"
echo "${STRING1}" 
# My name is James

NAME="${STRING1#???}"
echo "${NAME}" 
# James
```

Comment: What is your question? looks like Q/A session within yourself

Comment: @Inian There is an option to share knowledge. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: It is perfectly alright, its just its not verbose enough on what you are trying to do and how you solved it, may be care to add a little more explanation? I did not down-vote BTW

Comment: @Inian thanks for suggestion!

Comment: You don't need to escape anything, just `"${STRING1##* }"` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Inian could you provide an example? Add an answer, if you know better way to do this with built-in tools

Comment: I can't unless you let people know what is your requirement clearly with a sample input and expected output as part of your question.

Comment: What's your question exactly? the fact that there are spaces is completely irrelevant. I'm not quite sure what your point is…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative**: `FOO=${FOO//$WORDTOREMOVE/}`

```
$ STRING1="My name is James"
$ NAME="${STRING1//My name is /}"
$ echo "${NAME}"
James
```

**Update as per  @gniourf_gniourf's suggestion** : `FOO=${FOO/#$WORDTOREMOVE/}`

```
$ NAME="${STRING1/#My name is /}"
$ echo "${NAME}"
James
```

Comment: Better written as `"${string1/#My name is /}"`: don't need `//`, and since question asks for _prefix,_ better anchor it with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you have to escape special symbols in the prefix string.

```
NAME="${STRING1#My\ name\ is\ }"
echo "${NAME}"
# James
```

The same thing with suffices.

Comment: What are you talking about? why do you need to “escape special symbols”? what happens if you don't?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf hm.. really. I spent around 30 minutes investigating why "${STRING1#My name is }" was not working. So it is better to delete the question.

Comment: @AndriiAbramov: If you still have a problem in mind, feel free to post it as a proper question with necessary details on sample input and output.